# Hiding div on specific text in HREF

Tags: jquery, regex

I've seen similar questions but they are on a simpler side: if div contains specific text then hide it. Which works.

In my case I have more complex structure that dynamically changing. It can be a number of divs within divs with some javascript in the mix.

From the below example, I need to hide a div (or apply a class with hide to it) if any of the element has href with a specific ID in it: "`?id=my-text`"

```
<div **id="top-div"**>
    <div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        some java script code here...
        </script>
        <a target="_blank" href="some_very_long_url_that_contains_an_id_im_looking_for?id=my-text&bunch_of_other_parameters" width="300" height="250" border="0" alt="" style=" _width:298px; _height:248px; _overflow:hidden; border:1px solid #000000;margin:-1px;"></a>
        <script>
        some java script code here...
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried the following but without any luck:

```
$.expr[":"].containsNoCase = function(el, i, m) {
    var search = m[3];
    if (!search) return false;

    var pattern = new RegExp(search,"i");
    return pattern.test($(el).text());
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div a:containsNoCase('?id=my-text')").parent('div').hide();
});
```

**[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/msna997j/)**

**EDIT:** One thing I missed is that the ID of the very top div that I need to hide is static: "top-div". And I'd like to apply text search logic only do divs inside the "top-div" and not to the whole page.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /?id=my-text/: Nothing to repeat`

Comment: You probably don't want to include the question mark in your query string search. It's possible that your parameters won't always be in the same order.

Comment: I don't get why don't you use: `$("a[href*='?id=my-text']").parent('div'). hide();` ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a filter instead

```
$('#top-div').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('a').toArray().some(function(item) {
        return item.search.toLowerCase().indexOf('id=my-text') !== -1;
    });
}).hide();
```

Comment: Looks good. Added a reference to the parent div. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/msna997j/2/

Comment: It shouldn't need a reference to the parent, it's already targeting the parent DIV of the anchor

Comment: OP seems to want one level above that, no? Anyway, you might add some documentation. I'm an experienced developer and still have a bit of trouble swallowing that whole. :)

Comment: @MyroslavTedoski - it's still the same code, just filter that DIV instead of all of them

Answer (score 2):

Just apply this selector when you want apply CSS directly on a matching element:

```css
[href*=my-text] {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="?id=my-text">Link</a><br>
    <a href="?id=your-text">Link</a><br>
    <a href="?id=her-text">Link</a>
</div>
```

---

If the element to apply your CSS is a parent, use some JS like this:

```js
var target = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];

if (target.querySelectorAll("[href*=my-text]")[0]) {
    target.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="?id=my-text">Link</a><br>
    <a href="?id=your-text">Link</a><br>
    <a href="?id=her-text">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <a href="?id=his-text">Link</a><br>
    <a href="?id=your-text">Link</a><br>
    <a href="?id=her-text">Link</a>
</div>
```

---

You could also create your own function to apply that in any situations:

```js
function ifInnerSelector(targetSelector, innerSelector, callback) {
    var targets = document.querySelectorAll(targetSelector);
    [].forEach.call(targets, function (target) {
        var matched = target.querySelectorAll(innerSelector)[0];
        if (matched) {
            callback(null, target, matched);
        } else {
            callback(new Error("No matched item found."), target, null);
        }
    });
} 

ifInnerSelector(".container", "[href*=my-text]", function (err, target, matched) {
  if (err) {
    // Do something in case of error.
    return false;
  }
  target.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="?id=my-text">Link</a><br>
    <a href="?id=your-text">Link</a><br>
    <a href="?id=her-text">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <a href="?id=his-text">Link</a><br>
    <a href="?id=your-text">Link</a><br>
    <a href="?id=her-text">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <a href="?id=my-text">Link</a><br>
    <a href="?id=your-text">Link</a><br>
    <a href="?id=her-text">Link</a>
</div>
```

---

With librarie like jQuery you also can do this:

```
$("[href*=my-text]").closest(".container").css("background-color", "#f00");
```

or

```
$("[href*=my-text]").parents(".container:first").css("background-color", "#f00");
```